# BeautifulSoup could not get everything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

2 weeks ago, I could read everything in the source code of this url: http://camelcamelcamel.com/Jaybird-Sport-Wireless-Bluetooth-Headphones/product/B013HSW4SM?active=price_amazon

However, today, when I am running the same code again, all the historical price could not appear in soup.... Do you know how to fix this problem?

Here's my python code (it worked well!)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://camelcamelcamel.com/Jaybird-Sport-Wireless-Bluetooth-Headphones/product/B013HSW4SM?active=price_amazon'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url),'html.parser')
lst = soup.find_all('tbody')
for tbody in lst:
    trs = tbody.find_all('tr')
    for elem in trs:
        tr_class = elem.get('class')
        if tr_class != None:
            if tr_class[0] == 'highest_price' or tr_class[0] == 'lowest_price':
                tds = elem.find_all('td')
                td_label = tds[0].get_text().split(' ')[0]
                td_price = tds[1].get_text()
                td_date = tds[2].get_text()
                print td_label, td_price, td_date
        else:
            tds = elem.find_all('td')
            td_label = tds[0].get_text().split(' ')[0]  
            if td_label == 'Average':
                td_price = tds[1].get_text()
                print td_label, td_price  

ps = soup.find_all('p')
for p in ps:
    p_class = p.get('class')
    if p_class != None and len(p_class) == 2 and p_class[0] == 'smalltext' and p_class[1] == 'grey':
        p_text = p.get_text()
        m = re.search('since([\w\d,\s]+)\.', p_text)
        if m:
            date = m.group(1)
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, ' %b %d, %Y')
            print datetime.date.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure about the solution, but you should generally avoid of so much list indexing and `find_all` clauses. The reason is that the position or number of elements change much more easily than things like class, ids and so on. So I would recommend to use rather css selectors.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the source code, it seems like the historical price data is accessed via JavaScript.  As such, you'll need to find a way to emulate a real browser. Personally, I use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) for these kinds of tasks.